# Authentication via managed identity for blueprint assignment

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rest-api, azure-blueprints

I have to assign a blueprint via Rest API ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/blueprints/assignments/create-or-update#assignment-with-user-assigned-managed-identity-at-subscription-scope))

How can I get token with managed identity? Managed Identity is like below:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx/resourcegroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/xxx",
 "name": "xxx",
 "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
 "location": "westeurope",
 "tags": {},
 "properties": {
     "tenantId": "xxx",
     "principalId": "xxx",
     "clientId": "xxx"
 }
}
```

The enterprise app that created with managed identity hasn't any client secret. How can I get token for assign the the blueprint via api?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't but you also don't need to - to create the BP Assignment you need the token of a user/principal that has permissions to create assignments at that scope.

The resources created during assignment will use the MSIs context and that's handled by the Blueprint itself.

That help?